# Cannot configure Bounded Mailbox for Routees of RoundRobinPool

Tags: scala, akka

When I try to set bounded-mailbox for routees of a pool (RoundRobinPool) in configuration file, somehow Akka ignores the mailbox configuration.

Here is the configuration I use:

```
bounded-mailbox {
    mailbox-type = "akka.dispatch.BoundedMailbox"
    mailbox-capacity = 1
    mailbox-push-timeout-time = 1s
}

akka.actor.deployment {
    /singletestactor {
        mailbox = bounded-mailbox
}

    /groupedtestactor {
        mailbox = bounded-mailbox

        router = round-robin-pool
        nr-of-instances = 5
    }
}
```

And here is the test code:

```
object MailboxTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
    val singleTestActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[TestActor], "singletestactor")
    for (i <- 1 to 10) {
      singleTestActor ! Hello(i)
    }


    val groupedTestActor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[TestActor].withRouter(FromConfig, "groupedtestactor")
    for (i <- 1 to 1000) {
      groupedTestActor ! Hello(i)
    }
  }
}

class TestActor extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case Hello(i) => {
      println(s"Hello($i) - begin!")
      Thread.sleep(10000)
      println(s"Hello($i) - end!")
    }
  }
}

case class Hello(i: Int)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or there is no way to define mailbox for routees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add mailbox.requirements configuration in application.conf;

```
akka.actor.mailbox.requirements {
  "akka.dispatch.BoundedMessageQueueSemantics" = bounded-mailbox
}
```

Then need to extend `TestActor` like this;

```
class TestActor extends Actor with RequiresMessageQueue[BoundedMessageQueueSemantics]
```

See the documentation [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/mailboxes.html) for mailbox configuration.

I also created round robin pool like this;

```
val groupedTestActor = actorSystem.actorOf(FromConfig.props(Props[TestActor]), "groupedtestactor")
```

Comment: but what if I want to assign other or custom mailbox to that Actor, can I do that with a configuration change?

Comment: Yes you can; check this link; http://letitcrash.com/post/54099834993/22-spotlight-mailbox-requirements "If the actor has a different mailbox configured in deployment, then that will override this mapping."

Comment: hey @Fatih, here is a better way to configure mailbox for routees - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/JU722c10Dqg